# File Download Listener - Chrome Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, listener

Is there any way a google chrome extensions can detect whether a download was initiated? I could get all of the links and figure out which ones aren't html files and listen for those requests, but there are lots of exceptions and room for error, like having a pdf file open in the browser instead of download for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to suggest that this is possible in the [Chrome API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) and I see no way of doing it using the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) so I can only think that this is possible using an [NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) which may be overkill.

Do you really need to do this?

Comment: There's no extension API that supports this use case, so I'd suggest filing a feature request at http://new.crbug.com/ along with some problems you see an API like this solving.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible via the `chrome.downloads` extension API. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads for details.